# Want to create array of random integers in ascending order

Tags: java

I am currently working on a simple program where you're asked "How many random numbers between 0 - 999 do you want?" You enter a value (lets say 3), and it prints "Here are your numbers:" "213 52 821".
How do I go about making the random numbers print in **ascending** **order**, from smallest to biggest. I don't want you to write the code for me, just some pointers.

I am really new to programming

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);                                                    
    System.out.print("How many random numbers between 0 - 999 do you want? ");     
    int value = scan.nextInt(); 
    System.out.println("Here are your numbers:");

    int randomArray[]=new int[value]; 

    for(int i = 0; i<value; i++)
    {   
        randomArray [i] = (int) (Math.random () * 999); 
        System.out.println(randomArray[i]);
    }   
}  
}
```

Comment: Use a list instead of an array and you get that behavior for free. Also you have Arrays helper methods to sort an Array. You might want check this post out.:https://www.baeldung.com/java-sorting

Comment: You could sort your `randomArray` before printing it.

Comment: Use `Random.nextInt(1000)` instead of `Math.random() * 999`. There's a bias in your expression, so that 999 is impossible and 0 is more likely than it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have done most of the work. You just need to sort the resulting array.

Use `Arrays.sort(randomArray)` to sort the array.

Edit: You can print the array outside for-loop with `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(randomArray));`

Edit 2: In response to your comment, replace the for-loop with this code:

```
for(int i = 0; i<value; i++)
{   
    randomArray [i] = (int) (Math.random () * 999);
}  
Arrays.sort(randomArray);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(randomArray));
```

Edit 3: Replace the for loop in you code with this code if you want both ascending and descending order.

```
int[] ascendingArray = randomArray.clone();
Arrays.sort(ascendingArray);
int[] descendingArray= ascendingArray.clone();
Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(descendingArray));

// These two lines print the random array in ascending order.
System.out.println("Sorted array (ascending order):");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ascendingArray));

// These two lines print the random array in descending order.
System.out.println("Sorted array (descending order):");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(descendingArray));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I found that method but I don't know how to implement it into the code.

Comment: Oh okay, so the "Arrays.sort" does it for you? Like is it always in ascending order or can you change that? 
Thank you so much

Comment: @Yoneslide123 `Arrays.sort(arr)` sorts in an ascending order. If you want it to be in descending order, you can either use `Arrays.sort(arr, Collections.reverseOrder())` or you can simply reverse the array after sorting with `Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(myArray))`.

Comment: How would you copy the random array, to print in normal order as well?

Comment: If you want to copy the array, use this: `int[] copy = randomArray.clone();`. Putting everything together: `Arrays.sort(randomArray); int[] copy = randomArray.clone(); Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(randomArray));
System.out.println("Sorted array (ascending order):");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(copy));
System.out.println("Sorted array (descending order):");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(randomArray));`

Comment: Where would I put that? And doesn't this make it in ascending order as well?
So for instance I want the program to first print the "5 or whatever you input" random numbers and then "here are the numbers in ascending order".

Comment: If you were to sort them in even and odd numbers, how would you do it?

Answer (score 0):

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
                                                   
    System.out.print("How many random numbers between 0 - 999 do you want? "); 
    
    int value = scan.nextInt(); 
    System.out.println("Here are your numbers:");
    int randomArray[]=new int[value]; 
    for(int i = 0; i<value; i++)
    {   
        randomArray [i] = (int) (Math.random () * 999); 

        //System.out.println(randomArray[i]);
    } 

   Arrays.sort(randomArray);

   System.out.println(randomArray.toString());  

  } 
}
```